# VISIO connector

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio

I want to know if I delete the middle manager, the connections to the middle manager will be transferred to the next highest manager instead of getting deleted. Is there a way to make this happen.

Is there a way to make the connectors connect automatically?

Comment: Move and attach the connectors to the next highest manager first, then delete the middle manager ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume this change is already reflected in your database? If so, you could re-upload it to create a new org chart in Visio.
https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-a-Visio-organization-chart-abb3dd17-2692-439f-9945-3a015767d96a#bm5

Comment: Can you summarize the linked article? Link-only answer can become invalid if the linked page becomes unavailable.